# Which module to patch

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-3.4, python-unittest

I have the following directory

```
/root
  /app
      /api
          my_api.py
      /service
          my_service.py
  /tests
     test_api.py
```

my_api.py

```
import app
def run_service():
     app.service.my_service.service_function()
```

test_api.py

```
@patch('app.service.my_service.service_function')
test_run_service(self,mock_service):
     mock_service.return_value = 'Mock'
     response = self.client.get(url_for('api.run_service')
     self.assertTrue(response == expected_responce)
```

The above works. What I cant figure out, is which module I need to patch, in case I wanted to import `service_function` in my_apy.py like this:

```
from app.service.my_service import service_function
```

If I do the import like above, mock stops working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to patch out `app.api.my_api.service_function`, since that is the global name already bound to the imported object:

```
@patch('app.api.my_api.service_function')
test_run_service(self, mock_service):
     mock_service.return_value = 'Mock'
     response = self.client.get(url_for('api.run_service')
     self.assertTrue(response == expected_responce)
```

See the [*Where to patch* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch):

> The basic principle is that you patch where an object is *looked up*, which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined.

Comment: I had read that before but now I think I can understand it better. Had to use app.my_api.service_function by the way. Thank you

Comment: Ah, yes, include the package name here.